# after npm install , what is that color stand for?

Tags: node.js, npm

[image]

what is orange color stand for ? and others?

Where is npm document said about it?

Comment: The colors don't appear to be noted in the documentation, but the "yellow on black" (orange in your terminal theme) appears to highlight changes – packages that were actually installed by the command. The gray packages are those that were already present in the `node_modules` directory, installed by a previous `npm` command.